# JSF - how to force UI refresh?

Tags: java, jsf

I have two panels on my website. I use the first one (there is a list of users) to select a user, whose data I want to change on the second panel (I use AJAX to do that). When I try to change these data and validation error occurs it's impossible to change a choosen user because the second panel is still displaying previous UI component values (they aren't read from the model again). How can I force JSF to refresh UI component values using model values?

Answer (score 1):

Most a4j components have a reRender attribute, which you supply with a list of ids for portions of your layout that should be refreshed.

If you supply some code, we can probably suggest something a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the command with immediate=true, so you skip validations and apply request values altogether, and use EL parameters to update your stuff.

Since you provided no code, I'll invent some:
`<h:commandLink action="#{userController.showUser(selectedUser)}" immediate="true"  value="Show user"/>`

If that's not possible (e.g. you use a real list, that needs to be submitted), just create 2 `<h:form>`s. Forms submit data independently, so they won't step on each other toes with validations.